# newsletter mailservers - how to avoid blocklists?

Tags: email, mail-server, mailing-lists

I am working for a small company and we are sending out newsletter-emails to our customers like every 3 months. That are about 2000 emails every time.

we are using our own (old access & outlook) solution to send out the emails.

the problem with our recent mailings is that our provider's mailserver sometimes seems to be listed in "block-lists" or "spam-lists". so the email gets recjected by the receiver's provider.
this happens for about 10% of the emails sent.

we are a small company and I guess we cannot afford an expensive "professional" solution.

so my main question is: *what can we do to avoid this?*

we don't even know which of our provider's email-servers will send the emails before it happens. so there is no way to look up some of the popular block-lists.
switching between 2-3 providers would maybe worth a try - but in the end it's very random which of the servers is on which blocklist.

is there a solution we can do ourselves (we got C# and PHP programmers) ?
is there a "cheap" professional solution?

how do big professional services like "mailchimp" handle these problems?

thanks for any help!

Comment: You can send the email on behalf of some one else meaning if they block it, they block the IP and domain of the sender (not original company). This means buy a new domain name and a new IP address! However, the end user may not trust the email as not come from trusted source. Also, use tools to ensure your email spam score is slow and send over a long time. I'm overly cautious and send via my own server but last mail shot to 5k took 5 days - I send up to 6 emails a minute (and only send during certain times of day). That number is more arbitrary than scientific but I've never been black listed

Comment: @Dave thanks for your comment. if you send the email on behalf of someone else - doesn't the receiving mailserver still see the sending server's IP address? our provider's server has been blocked by IP address in some lists, afaik.

Comment: It's quite possible yes but things like that can be masked etc. But this gets into other complications and usually results in emails being blocked by their spam filters. The only advice I can give is send is small bunchs. Send 5 emails per minute, you'll hit the 2k mark in the day! All email, at any level, can be classified as spam. You will never get around this

Comment: @Dave ok, thank you very much. yes, we got a delay like this for sending them. and i guess we are not the reason the server gets into those blocklists. and I still wonder how big companies or professional services avoid being blocked by such lists.

Comment: Some mail shots I've done have been in the 10s of thousands (never hundreds though) - and for us the same rule applied. Send it slowly over time. Also, if it's a very successful email, you need to be able to deal with it, and we didn't have the staff to have coped if 1k customers called during a mail shot , let alone if 10k did!

Comment: One of my servers was hacked (due to me not setting a password strength rule (oops)) and my server ended up sending hundreds of thousands of spam emails! I got temporarily blocked by one or two providers only (and was able to reset those pretty quickly).  I think getting black list is probably quite hard so I wouldn't panic. I work on AME (http://www.amemailer.com) which is why I know this, although we are still working on the website :S Eventually, I'll be providing the mail software (for free) as a link

Comment: @Dave well, the problem is - it's not our server - it's usually one of the mailservers from our provider. some of our provider's other customers gets the server on some blocklists and we are suffering from this.. 
but yes, if you make a "false positive report" the server's IP gets deleted from the list pretty fast.

Comment: Then I suggest you get your own server, or VPS. Or change server. I used to use accu-web for mail shots. Hardware was slow but for mail shots (and a database to store results of opens/click throughs etc) it managed OK. You could easily do this on a subdomain, such as name@mailing.companyname.com. Of course, are you sure the issue is with the server and that the domain hasn't been blocked?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered (semi-)automatic resending rejected messages via another ISP?
Using [VERP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VERP) may simplify "bounce management".

Be warned: some brain dead email providers "dev null" (drop without any notice) messages "classified as spam".